# write csv from dictionary

Tags: python, django, csv, dictionary

Good day to all,

I would like to write a csv file from a dictionary. And followed everything here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/ I just changed the csv_data to a dictionary

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="some_file(%s).csv"'

csv_data = {'data' : [('quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jump'), ('over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog'), 'total' : 23, 'subtotal': 4}
t = loader.get_template('main/report/contract_position.txt')
c = Context({
            'csv_data' : csv_data,
            })

response.write(t.render(c))
return response
```

in my .txt file

```
"header1", "header2", "header3", "header4", "total", "subtotal"
{% for item in csv_data %}
???? #what should be here. Cuz I can't do something item.0|addslashes. It only takes out the first character of the string
{% endfor %}
```

In which I want to produce something like.

```
header1 header2 header3 header4
quick   brown   fox    jump    
over    the     lazy   dog
total   subtotal
23      4
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

def your_view(request, ...):
    csv_data = {
        'data': [
            ('quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jump'),
            ('over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog')
        ],
        'total': 23,
        'subtotal': 4
    }

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="some_file.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4'])
    writer.writerows(csv_data['data'])
    writer.writerow(['tota', 'subtotal'])
    writer.writerow([csv_data['total'], csv_data['subtotal']])
    return response
```

Comment: You sir is my savior! Really really appreciated your response. Thanks you.